# Inserir texto nas imagens

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

Tenho um Switch que de acordo com o status dado ele joga uma imagem, porém eu gostaria de jogar também a numeração desse status na imagem(aquele texto que geralmente ao encostarmos na imagem ele aparece). Gostaria de saber se há alguma propriedade que faz isso. Segue o código que eu fiz.

```
          switch (codParc)
                {
                    case 1:
                        imgStats.ImageUrl = "../images/yellowStatus.png";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        imgStats.ImageUrl = "../images/yellowStatus.png";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        imgStats.ImageUrl = "../images/greenStatus.png";
                        break;
                    default:
                        imgStats.ImageUrl = "../images/neutralStatus.png";
                        break;
                }
```

Para ter uma noção do que a imagem têm que apresentar, seria mais ou menos isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: WebForms, WPF. WinForms, MVC?

Comment: @jbueno WebForms

Comment: @DanielNicodemos, qual componente você está utilizando para setar a imagem?

Comment: @DanielNicodemos você quer dizer ToolTip?

Comment: @PedroFilipe Estou utilizando a biblioteca  System.Web.UI.WebControls da classe Image e o Drawing.

Comment: @Marconi Essa é a minha dúvida, qual é a biblioteca para jogar um texto na imagem, semelhante a lógica que eu estou utilizando ali. Por exemplo: 
imgStats.ImageUrl ="...";
imgStats.ImageText ="blablabla";
break;
Não sei se ToolTip satisfaz essa minha condição. Se satisfazer, me diz como por favor :)

Comment: @DanielNicodemos o Exemplo dado pela Diéfani pode te ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Melhorando a resposta por ajuda dos colegas nos comentários e respostas posteriores dos colegas, o código ficará assim:

```
switch (codParc)
                {
                    case 1:
                        imgStats.ImageUrl = "../images/yellowStatus.png";
                        imgStats.ToolTip = "1";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        imgStats.ImageUrl = "../images/yellowStatus.png";
                        imgStats.ToolTip = "2";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        imgStats.ImageUrl = "../images/greenStatus.png";
                        imgStats.ToolTip = "4";
                        break;
                    default:
                        imgStats.ImageUrl = "../images/neutralStatus.png";
                        break;
                }
```

Onde é gerado o texto do status de acordo com o Switch.

Comment: use o botão de edição para editar sua pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

O ToolTip faz o que você está precisando, segue abaixo um exemplo de como ficaria sem o Switch.

```
<asp:Image ID="Imagem1" runat="server"
       AlternateText="Smiley Face"
       ImageAlign="left"
       ToolTip="Status da numeração"
       ImageUrl="../images/yellowStatus.png" />
```